# `docker run -v` doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, docker

I'm experimenting with a Docker image repository cloned from https://github.com/amouat/example_app.git (which is based on another repository: https://github.com/mrmrcoleman/python_webapp).

The structure of this repository is:

```
├── Dockerfile
 ├── example_app
 │   ├── app
 │   │   ├── __init__.py
 │   │   └── views.py
 │   └── __init__.py
 ├── example_app.wsgi
```

After building this repository with tag `example_app`, I try to mount a directory from the host in the repository:

```
$ pwd
/Users/satoru/Projects/example_app
$ docker run -v $(pwd):/opt -i -t example_app bash 
root@3a12236a1471:/# ls /opt/example_app/
root@3a12236a1471:/# exit
$ ls example_app
__init__.py app         run.py
```

Note that when I tried to list files in `/opt/example_app` in the container it turned out to be empty.

What's wrong in my configuration?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. In my test `/opt/example_app/` is not empty. Make sure you are using the latest version of  docker and rebuild both python_webapp and example_app

Comment: @Thomas I'm using boot2docker on OSX, does that make any difference?

Comment: I'm using Vagrant on windows

Comment: @Thomas since you are using boot2docker the host is not your OSX but the Linux in the Boot2docker VM. This means that the directory you are mounting must exist inside the vm.

Comment: @AbelMuiño I am not using boot2docker or OSX. Maybe you meant satoru ?

Comment: @AbelMuiño I've tried the same docker command inside the vm and it worked as expected. Guess I just can't do that mounting directly on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python_webapp

MAINTAINER amouat

ADD example_app.wsgi /var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi
CMD service apache2 start && tail -F /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

So you won't find the files you mentioned since there were non`ADD`-d in the Dockerfile. Also, this is not going to work unless `python_webapp` installs apache and creates /var/www/flaskapp and /var/log/apache2 exists. Without knowing what these other customs parts do, it is hard to know what to expect.

Comment: I've added a link to the `python_webapp` repository in my question.

Comment: due to `-v $(pwd):/opt` option of the `docker run` command it is expected to find the files under `/opt/example_app` of the container without having to `ADD` the files in the Dockerfile.